# storing negative number in decimal field of mysql table as of version 5.0.3

Tags: mysql, types

1. My table has few fields with an amount column of type decimal.
2. This column will have either a deposited amount (a positive value) or a withdraw amount (a negative value).
3. I store the positive value as just 120 and the negative value as -50.
4. I sum the column and got the result as expected.
5. Mysql version is: 5.1.33-community.
6. When i checked mysql documentation about decimal i confused with their description.
7. > Before MySQL 5.0.3, if you inserted
   >   +0003.1 into a DECIMAL(5,1) column, it was stored as +0003.1. As of MySQL
   >   **5.0.3**, it is stored as 3.1. For negative numbers, a literal -
   >   character is no longer stored.
   >   Applications that rely on the older
   >   behavior must be modified to account
   >   for this change. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html
8. When i listed the rows in phpmyadmin i could see the negative sign and when i calculated the result was as expected. but the documentation said no sign will appear.
9. Is it good to store negative number in decimal(haven't i studied in school? confused)?... or do we have to use float.
10. I learn't that float would complicate calculations and was advised to stick with decimal for certain conditions.

    I would like to have suggestions for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I understand, the documentation is saying it won't store a *literal* "-" *character*, which means it's probably now doing what the other signed INTEGER fields have always done and it's storing a sign bit to denote negative numbers instead.

You're still seeing a minus sign preceding the number because it's being generated by MySQL as a result of that sign bit.

If you don't understand the sign bit, you can consider how a signed byte can store numbers from -128 to 127, while an unsigned byte can store numbers from 0 to 255.  That's because one of the 8 bits in a signed number is being used to store +/- (1 is negative, 0 is positive), while the remaining bits offer numbers up to 2^7 (-128 or 127).

So, for example, if the bits 1111 had a sign bit they would equal -7 (negative+4+2+1), but if they were unsigned they'd equal 15 (8+4+2+1).  It's still the same amount of bits being stored.

You may wonder why the negative bound in a signed number can use the 8th bit, while the positive bound is limited to the sum of the 7 bits (1 less than the 8th bit).  This is because 10000000 is considered to be both negative and the 8th bit simultaneously, because its representation of -0 otherwise is redundant with 00000000 which represents 0.  There's no distinction between negative and positive zero, so a negative most significant bit is always the value of that bit itself (but negative).

Comment: nice. so it maintain the sign status bit wise. hhmmm. ok.

Comment: Exactly; and a signed number (+/-) has half the positive range of an unsigned number because it has one fewer bit of capacity, and the other half of that range is negative.

Comment: Just a note -- usually negative numbers are encoded with [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), so `1111` in four-bit byte equals to `-1`

Comment: Thanks @Erbureth! I should have specified that my simplified example was using the 'sign-magnitude' method.