# storing negative value in mysql

Tags: mysql, decimal, mysql5, negative-number

How can I store negative value in mysql decimal? I have data from DMS to Decimal having negative values, so it is decimal and negative. So what can I use to store such value?

Comment: Column of type `numeric` or any flavour of myriad of floats available with MySQL and then simply use `INSERT INTO your_table SET your_number = '-1000.99';`, replace the SQL command with one you need of course.

Comment: You can store either positive or negative values in Decimal columns. WHat have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760822/storing-negative-number-in-decimal-field-of-mysql-table-as-of-version-5-0-3

Comment: @xQbert: I'd say that doesn't apply. The other Q is about changes related over different versions, whereas this is "what type do I use"

Comment: Possibly just some confusion over signed vs unsigned?

Comment: I wrote some thing from mysql site that it doesnot deal with negative number but maybe I didn't read correctly as I was going through many things at that time. So let me try negative

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use MySQL [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html) type?

> Standard SQL requires that DECIMAL(5,2) be able to store any value with five digits and two decimals, so values that can be stored in the salary column range from -999.99 to 999.99

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to store a **negative integer** - (**INT**) will work nicely, unless it's not UNSIGNED.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

In case you want to store a **negative decimal** - (**DECIMAL**) is the way to go, as GBN mentioned above.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Comment: *unless it's UNSIGNED.
If it is an unsigned INT minimum value will be 0