# Cannot insert the value '-1' into database

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot insert the value "-1" into database, the table set the field is `int(10)`.
I don't know what the problem is. Could you help me. thank you.

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO attendance_count(username,date,count_time,appendix)VALUES('$applicant','$date1','-1','$altext')";
mysql_query($sql2);
```

Comment: which data type is *count_time* ?

Comment: the data type is int(10).

Comment: then you should not put -1 inside quotes.

Comment: What does "cannot insert" mean? Does the statement insert no data at all? Do you get an unexpected value in `count_time`? If so, which?

Comment: please give me the example. thank you.

Comment: $sql2="INSERT INTO attendance_count(username,date,count_time,appendix)VALUES('$applicant','$date1',-1,'$altext')";

Comment: How do you notice that you cannot insert -1? Please show us your evidence, any error messages or the wrong result in the database.

Comment: print $sql2 and send it via phpmyadmin. maybe your query has an error.

Answer (score 1):

don't put single quote since its an int.

Comment: Doesn't matter. MySQL has to parse it in any case, because the SQL string is a STRING. Quotes don't change anything in MySQL.

Comment: I try to delete the single quote, after that run the code. it can not insert the data into database. no any data in the database.

Comment: int should be `SIGNED`. Mysql states that all integer types can have an optional (nonstandard) attribute UNSIGNED. Unsigned type can be used to permit only nonnegative numbers in a column or when you need a larger upper numeric range for the column. For example, if an INT column is UNSIGNED, the size of the column's range is the same but its endpoints shift from -2147483648 and 2147483647 up to 0 and 4294967295.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the column isn't `UNSIGNED`

Comment: -1 Read the original question, it is stated that the field type is `int(10)`

Answer (score 1):

> the documentation is saying it won't store a literal "-" character,
>   which means it's probably now doing what the other signed INTEGER
>   fields have always done and it's storing a sign bit to denote negative
>   numbers instead.
>
> You're still seeing a minus sign preceding the number because it's
>   being generated by MySQL as a result of that sign bit.
>
> If you don't understand the sign bit, you can consider how a signed
>   byte can store numbers from -128 to 127, while an unsigned byte can
>   store numbers from 0 to 255. That's because one of the 8 bits in a
>   signed number is being used to store +/- (1 is negative, 0 is
>   positive), while the remaining bits offer numbers up to 2^7 (-128 or
>   127).
>
> So, for example, if the bits 1111 had a sign bit they would equal -7
>   (negative+4+2+1), but if they were unsigned they'd equal 15 (8+4+2+1).
>   It's still the same amount of bits being stored.
>
> You may wonder why the negative bound in a signed number can use the
>   8th bit, while the positive bound is limited to the sum of the 7 bits
>   (1 less than the 8th bit). This is because 10000000 is considered to
>   be both negative and the 8th bit simultaneously, because its
>   representation of -0 otherwise is redundant with 00000000 which
>   represents 0. There's no distinction between negative and positive
>   zero, so a negative most significant bit is always the value of that
>   bit itself (but negative).

Comment: Here's the original [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760822/storing-negative-number-in-decimal-field-of-mysql-table-as-of-version-5-0-3)

Comment: yes I extracted it here because It's the same question. I guess there is nothing wrong since It's the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

the column where youre entering the value -1 should be `SIGNED`

`INT(SIGNED) values can be a minimum of-2147483648 to a maximum of 2147483647
INT(UNSIGNED) values can be a minimum of 0 to a maximum of 4294967295`

Comment: -1 Read the original question, it is stated that the field type is `int(10)`

Comment: using the phpmyadmin, I can change the value is "-1".